# How to handle user functions with unkown number of arguments for performance measurements?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a performance test that can run functions with 
different number of arguments.
Something like this:

```
// optimization.cpp
struc Command{
    unkown_type fun;
} command1;  

perf_test(Command exec){
     unkown_type ptr = exec.fun
     // start timer
     ptr();
     // stop timer
}

// main.cpp
user_function1(double x[], double y[]);
user_function2(double x[], double y[], int z, double A[]);
// somehow bind function 
command1.exec = user_function1
perf_test(command1);
```

Is there somehow a way of doing this and getting good results e.g. function inlining and so on or is this simply not possible?

I know about `std::function` and `std::bind` but unfortunately std::function 
has a large overhead which makes no sense for my performance measurements.

Comment: How will you be passing arguments to the function wrapped in your hypothetical `perf_test`?

Comment: Until I now we did not have a variable number of arguments, simply passed them along with the Command struct and then called the function with them like this `command1.exec(exec.A, exec.B);`
First I was thinking that we could use a function without arguments and then somehow bind them or use lambdas but I cannot get my head around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

```
template <class Function, class ...Args>
auto perf_test(Function &&f, Args && ...args) {
    // start timer
    std::forward<Function>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
    // stop timer
    //print or return or store time
}
```

To be used like

```
auto passed_time = perf_test(user_function1, somex, somey);
```

If you really must have your `Command` struct you can store the `args` in a `std::tuple` and then use `std::apply` to call the function. If you put the time measuring code around the function and then assign it to an `std::function` you can use the convenience of `std::function` without its overhead influencing your measurement. This can look something like

```cpp
template <class Function, class... Args>
std::function<std::chrono::nanoseconds()> make_perf_test(Function &&f,
                                                         Args &&... args) {
    return [f = std::forward<Function>(f),
            args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]() mutable {
        const auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::apply(std::forward<decltype(f)>(f), std::move(args));
        return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
    };
}
```

to be used like

```cpp
auto uf1 = make_perf_test(user_function1, x, y);
std::cout << "user_function1 took " << uf1().count() << "ns\n";
```

This gives you an easy to store type `std::function<std::chrono::nanoseconds()>` that type-erases the parameters and arguments away while not including that overhead in the measurement.

There is are some tweaking spot. Maybe the lambda should not be `mutable` so that the arguments cannot change so that you can repeat the measurement. Also due to limitations of `std::function`, this requires that the function and parameters are copyable.

Comment: I thought vardict arguments would change the performance measurements?
I Will definitely try it.

Comment: Surely templates are compile time? i.e. no runtime performance. Maybe I'm wrong

Comment: That is exactly what I need as I have two unknown and one known function in my performance test. The unknowns are called inside the known.
I updated my question with what I have so far.
Can you clarify how to put the time measuring code around the desired function before wrapping it into a std::function, so that I can close the question?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variadic template for this.

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void invoke_func(F func, Args&&... args) {
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

You can then call that directly within your performance measuring code.